# How to I allow full access for an IAM user to a specific path within a bucket only?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, amazon-iam

### Background

- I have several buckets, each with a "Development" and "Production" folder inside.
- I have two accounts, `accountname-dev` and `accountname-prod`

### Goals

- I'd like `account-dev` to have full access (all actions) on BucketName/DEVELOPMENT
- I'd like `account-prod` to have full access (all actions) on BucketName/PRODUCTION

### Problem

Whenever I use the policy generator, it looks like I'm doing it wrong somehow. Adding a standard admin policy allows access to the documents fine, but my custom policy does not.

I added the policy using Amazon's IAM policy creation screen for a specific account.

The policy I'm trying to use is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "[Redacted]",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": "DEVELOPMENT/*"
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::RedactedBucketName"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Questions

- Is anything wrong with the policy above?
- Is this the only policy I need to add? Or do I need to add some sort of access capability at the bucket level too first?
- Even though Amazon's policy generation screen didn't include the full ARN for the principal, is it a best practice to include that anyway?

Comment: FYI, to the person who voted this off-topic: it is directly related to our development code failing. Thought about putting it on ServerFault, but there seem to be much less questions there for the same topic, so I assumed it belonged here.

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work this way:

Assign an IAM user policy only (no S3 bucket policy is needed) to individual user.

Check below  user policy. I created for the user `account-dev`, meaning, you have to apply this IAM policy to `account-dev` user.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRootLevelListingOfDevelopmentBucket",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::development-bucket-name"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:prefix": [
            ""
          ],
          "s3:delimiter": [
            "/"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListBucketIfSpecificPrefixIsIncludedInRequest",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::development-bucket-name"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": [
            "DEVELOPMENT/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserToReadWriteObjectData",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::development-bucket-name/DEVELOPMENT/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`AllowGroupToSeeBucketListInTheConsole` and `AllowRootLevelListingOfDevelopmentBucket` are needed for user to work from S3 console. If you do not want user to work from S3 console and want him to work only using APIs, then you can omit these 2 stanzas.

Similarly, you have create another user policy for `account-prod` and assign it to that user.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it turns out the original policy was okay, but it was another issue. I'll be deleting use question as a result, but appreciate your jumping in!